# MFC C++ lookup on CMAP

Tags: c++, mfc

When I use a `.lookup(key, value)` on a project member MFC `CMap`.
Does the return value, is by reference ?

Template:

```
CMap<ID_TYPE, ID_TYPE, CSimulatedRule, CSimulatedRule&> m_SimulatedRules;
```

If i edit value members, e.g `value.setAge(10);` will it change the value on `Map` ? or just the value object that I currently have ?

Code:

```
CSimulatedRule simulatedRule;
m_SimulatedRules.Lookup(ro.Id(),simulatedRule);
```

When editing `simulatedRule` it will edit the object on the `CMap`?

Answer (score 1):

This will not change the object in map.
Use PLookup instead.